# Sort strings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame in pandas and I want to sort it by column.
If I use `.sort_values()` like in the below code:

```
df.sort_values(by='id')
```

I get the output in the 'id' column as:

```
1075_2016-06-01_0_1
1075_2016-06-01_10_1
1075_2016-06-01_10_2
1075_2016-06-01_11_1
1075_2016-06-01_11_2
1075_2016-06-01_1_1
1075_2016-06-01_1_2
```

I expected:

```
1075_2016-06-01_0_1
1075_2016-06-01_1_1
1075_2016-06-01_1_2
1075_2016-06-01_10_1
1075_2016-06-01_10_2
1075_2016-06-01_11_1
1075_2016-06-01_11_2
```

What is the best way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution with [natsort](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for get indices of sorting values and change of original DataFrame by `loc`:

```
from natsort import index_natsorted, order_by_index

df2 = df.loc[order_by_index(df.index, index_natsorted(df['id']))]
```

Or split all values by `_`, then convert columns to integer and optionaly to datetimes, sorting for indices and last use `loc` with original `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df['id'].str.split('_', expand=True)
df1[[0,2,3]] = df1[[0,2,3]].astype(int)
df1[1] = pd.to_datetime(df1[1])

df2 = df.loc[df1.sort_values([0,1,2,3]).index]
print (df2)
                     id
0   1075_2016-06-01_0_1
5   1075_2016-06-01_1_1
6   1075_2016-06-01_1_2
1  1075_2016-06-01_10_1
2  1075_2016-06-01_10_2
3  1075_2016-06-01_11_1
4  1075_2016-06-01_11_2
```

Next solution with `argsort` for sorting and change order by indexing by positions with `iloc` for working with any index values:

```
f = lambda x: [int(x[0]), pd.to_datetime(x[1]), int(x[2]), int(x[3])]
df2 = df.iloc[df['id'].str.split('_').map(f).argsort()]
print (df2)
                     id
0   1075_2016-06-01_0_1
5   1075_2016-06-01_1_1
6   1075_2016-06-01_1_2
1  1075_2016-06-01_10_1
2  1075_2016-06-01_10_2
3  1075_2016-06-01_11_1
4  1075_2016-06-01_11_2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 'id' is not a pandas index it's just a column

Comment: @hyper - Yes, both solution working with `id` column.

Answer (score 1):

Guys thank you very much! The combination of the two solutions worked:

```
df['sort_val']= df['id'].str.split('_') 
f = lambda x: [int(x[0]), pd.to_datetime(x[1]), int(x[2]), int(x[3])]
df['sort_val'] = df['sort_val'].map(f)
df.sort_values(by='sort_val').drop('sort_val',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first split the values per underscores, and then sort these, like:

```
df['sort_val'] = df['id'].str.split('_')
df = df.sort_values('sort_val').drop('sort_val', 1)
```

The above should work on an arbitrary number of underscore separated values.

This gives us:

```
>>> df
                     id
0   1075_2016-06-01_0_1
1  1075_2016-06-01_10_1
2  1075_2016-06-01_10_2
3  1075_2016-06-01_11_1
4  1075_2016-06-01_11_2
5   1075_2016-06-01_1_1
6   1075_2016-06-01_1_2
>>> df['sort_val'] = df['id'].str.split('_')
>>> df = df.sort_values('sort_val').drop('sort_val', 1)
>>> df
                     id
0   1075_2016-06-01_0_1
5   1075_2016-06-01_1_1
6   1075_2016-06-01_1_2
1  1075_2016-06-01_10_1
2  1075_2016-06-01_10_2
3  1075_2016-06-01_11_1
4  1075_2016-06-01_11_2
```

Comment: for some reason this does not work if there are also other elements, for example: `1075_2016-06-01_1_3 1075_2016-06-01_2_0 1075_2016-06-01_6_0`

Comment: @hyper: for the given sample data, I get the items sorted in the order you provide these, which seems to be the correct sorting?